# PHP 5.4 + Nginx + APC = 502 Bad Gateway?

Tags: nginx, apc, php

I recently upgraded to PHP 5.4 and a month ago, APC wasn't compatible, so I downgraded back to PHP 5.3 and everything worked fine and dandy. However, I'd like to take advantage of the new features of PHP 5.4 and I cant seem to get it to work with my current setup. Supposedly, APC is now "compatible" as of their latest beta version, however I get the following errors:

[21-Apr-2012 22:56:53] WARNING: [pool www] child 12245 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 61.544928 seconds from start

[21-Apr-2012 22:56:51] WARNING: [pool www] child 12250 exited on signal 11 (SIGSEGV) after 43.367441 seconds from start

etc etc.

My setup is: nginx + php 5.4 via php-fpm plus APC. If I disable APC, everything works fine (albeit slowly haha).

Ive installed both the beta and the trunk versions and neither seem to work. I just get a 502 Bad Gateway error on all pages EXCEPT for a phpinfo(); page, which works just fine.

What can I do? I've googled everywhere.

Comment: For what its worth, you can grab the source code for the latest apc svn co http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/apc/trunk/ apc-trunk and then cd to the checkout dir and use pecl install package.xml to install as usual and then restart fpm and it should be ok.